# Auto-upload image feature with image browser module (e.g: Image picker)

Tags: 7, media

I am using the imagepicker module for browsing the uploaded images, I have tried searching for the auto-upload integration for this module but still no luck.

I am searching for any alternative way if there for similar thing (mainly I require image browser to use the already uploaded images, and implementing the auto-upload functionality on it).

Any suggestion/recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be posted as feature request in the image browser module issue queue?

Comment: @Molot - Yeah I have checked the issue already and its not there, my concern is if can be customized or if someone had tried the same. Or finding any other viable alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it would help, because I don't know what you mean by "auto" uplaod, but here is the configuration I use:

FileField Sources module
https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources

with IMCE module:
https://drupal.org/project/imce

FileField source is pretty usefull to present user a set of upload options for a single image field.

Comment: Ok.  Not sure again if it would help, but there is a FileField Sources Plupload module, here: https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload